# Notify with_items on ansible

Tags: ansible

i am downloading zip files from an url, i am using with_items for list of zip files in that location, i want to do a task (extract) for only the file downloaded. Since i am new to ansible i cant think of anything other than using with_items for downloading files, but i dont know how to make use of notify here, if i use notify below with_items how it will invoke only the file it has downloaded. To summarise , i want to download zip files which are changed, extract only the files which are downloaded and install only the files which are extracted. Since with_items has all the files listed in it , how can i achieve this workflow in ansible

```
- name: Download all files 
     get_url: url=http://url.com/{{ item }} dest=/home/user/downloads/{{ item }}  force=no
     with_items:
       - 1.zip
       - 2.zip
       - 3.zip
```

Comment: Register result of the first task and iterate over result instead of original files list. Loop result has per item changed status.

Comment: Can you show me a sample on how to do this?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpfull? First it downloads the files followed by extracting them.

```
    - hosts: all
      vars:
        - files:
           - 1.zip
           - 2.zip
           - 3.zip
      tasks:
       - name: Download all files 
           get_url: url=http://url.com/{{ item }} dest=/home/user/downloads/{{ item }}  force=no
         with_items: "{{ files }}"

       - name: extracting downloaded files
         unarchive:
          src: {{ item }}.zip
          dest: /var/lib/foo
          remote_src: True
         with_items: "{{ files }}"
```

Comment: it seems to be a basic one and will it serve my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - get_url:
        url: "{{ item }}"
        dest: /tmp/
      with_items:
        - https://yastatic.net/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js
        - https://yastatic.net/react/15.0.1/react.min.js
      register: downloads
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.dest }}"
      when: item | changed
      with_items: "{{ downloads.results }}"
```

Comment: thanks for taking time in answering this, however i dont understand what it does :(

Comment: i have some 10 files and i am registering the result , and i am extracting 6th file by checking when: output.results[6].changed == true , is this right approach?

Comment: why do you need to reference 6th file? just loop over each element in output.results and do the task only when `item.changed == true`.

Comment: lets say i have 10 files and each file has to be copied only when they are downloaded and extracted only when they are downloaded, how can i connect these 3 tasks..right now i have 3 tasks written and registering result of each and using when ..is this right approach?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I showed you in my answer. Register result and use when to run subsequent task selectively.

Comment: actually every file will go to different places, so i dont think i can write a single task to handle all the files to be copied, so download 1.zip, 2.zip, 3.zip , copy 1.zip to a location only when output.results[1].changed==true and i will register this copy task and i will call this variable in my extract task..is it right?

Comment: No. Try to understand concept. Sorry, but I'm out of further discussions.

Comment: if we are addressing a specific file, we need to reference it ..no other go